# How to get the current local time using the system time zone and UTC time from the server in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, datetime, utc

I have got the UTC time as `Sat, 19 May 2012 11:26:51 +0000` in the json response and have the system time zone as `+0530`. How can i convert the UTC time to the local time using the two available result? I want the date as `isoDate` format and time as `isoTime` format. Please help how to do that?

Comment: Are you sure you mean from the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert the JSON datetime to a Date Object (use the string without the +0000 timezone information) and add/subtract the client side timezoneOffset:

```
var received = new Date('Sat, 19 May 2012 11:26:51'),
    clientDate = new Date(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()*-60000 
                  + received.getTime());
//note: -60000 reverses the sign of the timezone offset 
//      clientDate is calculated in milliseconds.
//alternatively you can set [received] directly to the local datetime using:
received.setMinutes(received.getMinutes()+(-(new Date().getTimezoneOffset()));
```

In my timezone (GMT+2) `clientDate` now reads `Sat May 19 2012 13:26:51 GMT+0200`