# How to identify time zone of client machine using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

I need to capture local time zone of client based on the browser

Like if client comes from US: Time1 and

if client comes from India: Time2

```
JavaScript method to get datetime based on browser

save value in hidden field

call or execute above JavaScript function on server side

get back value from hidden field to server side.
```

Comment: Use documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTimezoneOffset

Comment: This seems to be copy-pasted directly from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16151736/get-local-time-zone-of-client-from-respective-browser, so some sort of pre-spam? (Protip: if you copy-paste content, make sure you don't copy things like "0 down vote favorite" image alt-text)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the current local time using the system time zone and UTC time from the server in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10664933/how-to-get-the-current-local-time-using-the-system-time-zone-and-utc-time-from-t)

Comment: juhana , thanks for your information !

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
<script>    
var offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset();
var timezones = {
  '-12': 'Pacific/Kwajalein',
  '-11': 'Pacific/Samoa',
  '-10': 'Pacific/Honolulu',
  '-9': 'America/Juneau',
  '-8': 'America/Los_Angeles',
  '-7': 'America/Denver',
  '-6': 'America/Mexico_City',
  '-5': 'America/New_York',
  '-4': 'America/Caracas',
  '-3.5': 'America/St_Johns',
  '-3': 'America/Argentina/Buenos_Aires',
  '-2': 'Atlantic/Azores',
  '-1': 'Atlantic/Azores',
  '0': 'Europe/London',
  '1': 'Europe/Paris',
  '2': 'Europe/Helsinki',
  '3': 'Europe/Moscow',
  '3.5': 'Asia/Tehran',
  '4': 'Asia/Baku',
  '4.5': 'Asia/Kabul',
  '5': 'Asia/Karachi',
  '5.5': 'Asia/Calcutta',
  '6': 'Asia/Colombo',
  '7': 'Asia/Bangkok',
  '8': 'Asia/Singapore',
  '9': 'Asia/Tokyo',
  '9.5': 'Australia/Darwin',
  '10': 'Pacific/Guam',
  '11': 'Asia/Magadan',
  '12': 'Asia/Kamchatka'
};
var a = timezones[-offset / 60];
document.cookie = "cookieName=" + a;
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks patel , i got an idea by your solution